# Create mod rewrite if the url has only 1 segment

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to ask a little help with Mod Rewrite.

I would like make a mod rewrite ONLY IF the url is like these:

```
https://example.com/segment
https://example.com/segment/
```

I would like to point the url to

```
https://www.example.com/?r=segment
```

And then redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/
```

Thank you so much! Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by " **and then redirect to** ?"

Comment: @Starkeen After it points to https://www.example.com/?r=segment, i will perform php script. And then after that i would like to redirect it to https://www.example.com/

Comment: I think you should insert a `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` to the end of your script.

Comment: @dr_debug thank you.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34798191/3822464 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule .* /?r=%1 [R,L]
```

Replace `[R,L]` with `[R=301,L]` when you're done testing if the redirect should be permanent (useful primarily for SEO reasons).

For the "And then redirect to" part of your question, in your /index.php script, put the following when you're ready to redirect:

```
header('Location: /');
exit;
```